# How to display username and email from firebase in android

Tags: java, android, kotlin

i am trying to get username and email for single user profile.

[image]

Comment: Why navigate to nested `child(uid)`? What does the structure look like?

Comment: Query q = firebaseDatabase.child("users").orderByChild("email").equalTo(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getEmail()); stell not displaying  savedInstanceStatge = null

Comment: I want get user name and email, to show on profile screen.

Comment: Can you post your firebase structure ?

Answer (score 0):

I think that firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid() return uid that is not the same as uid in FirebaseDatabase. You can user Query.

For example:

```
Query q = firebaseDatabase.child("users").orderByChild("email").equalTo(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getEmail());
```

Comment: I want get user name and email, to show on profile screen.

Comment: just say q.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener(...), it is same as your code.

Comment: Thanks sir. But i could not getting display

Answer (score 0):

You should use `addChildEventListener` instead of `addValueEventListener`, and write the code inside `onChildAdded`.

You can find the explanation from [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data):

> When working with lists, your application should listen for child
>   events rather than the value events used for single objects.